# Django, many to many query with annotations

Tags: django, django-queryset

So I have an person model that has a many to many relationship with a film model.

The `Film` model looks like this:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(db_index=True, unique = True)
    date = models.DateField()
    votes = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3 , decimal_places=1)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField('Person')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

`Person` model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()
    full = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=100,unique = True)
    short = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=100)
    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.full,)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full
```

I'm trying to get a query of the top 20 persons who have the best average rating with at least 20 films that have at least 250 votes.

So far I have this:

```
Person.objects.annotate(film_count=Count('film')).filter(film_count__gte=20).filter(film__votes__gte=250).annotate(avg_rating=Avg('film__rating')).order_by('-avg_rating')[:20]
```

but the results of that return persons with less than 20 films.

Comment: Can you please add the `Person` model and also; 1) have you tried the query in isolation - ie confirmed that `Person.objects.annotate(film_count=Count('film')).filter(film_count__gte=20)` is working (looks good) 2) have you looked at the resulting SQL query?

Comment: yes, that query in isolation works

Comment: Cool. Please paste in the resulting SQL query. Just a suggestion, add a `related_name` to your ManyToMany relationship ie `actors = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name="films")` for readability. You also might want to look at `Q` objects. ie `Person.objects.annotate(film_count=Count('film')).annotate(avg_rating=Avg('film__rating')).filter(Q(film__votes__gte=250) & Q(film_count__gte=20)).order_by('-avg_rating')[:20]`